# Concatenating strings in C. newline in output

Tags: c, concatenation, c-strings

I have strange problem where the output of the concatenation comes with a new line between each string input. I tried couple of different things eg. removing the dynamic memory allocation, copying strings into one another and then concatenating. the same issue is there. any ideas why?

Input:

```
> one
> two
```

Output:

```
> Result of concatenation: one
> two
```

here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    /* code */

    char string1[100];
    char string2[100];
    char *concat;

    fgets(string1,100,stdin);
    fgets(string2,100,stdin);

    unsigned int size = strlen(string1) + strlen(string2);

    concat = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * size);

    if (concat==NULL)
    {
        exit(0); 
    }

    strcat(concat,string1);
    strcat(concat,string2);

    printf("Result of concatenation: %s",concat);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters the function `fgets` can append the new line character to the entered strings. You should remove it. For example

```
fgets(string1,100,stdin);
string1[ strcspn( string1, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
fgets(string2,100,stdin);
string2[ strcspn( string2, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

Secondly you forgot about the terminating zero when was allocating memory. Instead of

```
unsigned int size = strlen(string1) + strlen(string2);
```

You have to write

```
size_t size = strlen(string1) + strlen(string2) + 1;
```

Futhermore the allocated memory is not initislaized. You have to write

```
concat[0] = '\0';
```

before these statements

```
strcat(concat,string1);
strcat(concat,string2);
```

And do not forget to free the allocated memory.

```
free( concat );
```

Comment: what's the difference between `unsigned int` and `size_t` ?

Comment: @BishoyAkmal An object of the type unsigned int can be too small to keep all values that the type size_t can hold. size_t is the returned type of the function strlen.

Answer (score 0):

From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html):

> `char *fgets(char *restrict s, int n, FILE *restrict stream);`
>
> ...
>
> The `fgets()` function shall read bytes from stream into the array
>   pointed to by `s`, until `n−1` bytes are read, **or a `<newline>` is read
>   and transferred to `s`**, or an end-of-file condition is encountered.
>   The string is then terminated with a null byte.

You are likely including the `\n` (new line characters) read by `fgets` in your concatenated array of characters.